# jQuery is one step late

Tags: jquery

I'm counting div children. That's div with id results which is container which accepts ajax result. Problem is that when I type something into search box(which is live search), my counter shows results for previous value of the search box. For instance, when I type "bel" it shows me count for "be" and so on. Why is that, and how to make it to work like "live" counter for any change inside container div?

```
$('#search, #description').on("keyup", function(){
        if($('#search_results').length>0){
            $('#search_results').remove();
        }
        $('#browse_wrapper').prepend("<p style='border-bottom: 1px solid #C5C5C5; margin-bottom: 20px;' id='search_results'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> <strong>"+$('div#results>div').length+"</strong> results for "+$('#search, #description').val()+"</p>");
    });
```

Ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // Icon Click Focus
    $('div.icon').click(function(){
        $('input#search').focus();
    });

    // Live Search
    // On Search Submit and Get Results
    function search() {
        var city = $('input#search').val();
        var description = $('input#description').val();

        //$('b#search-string').html(query_value);
        if(city !== '' || description !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_php/search.php",
                data: { city: city, desc: description},
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("div#results").html(html);
                }
            });
        }return false;    
    }

        $("input#search, input#description").live("keyup", function(e) {
            // Set Timeout
            clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

            // Set Search String
            var search_string_1 = $(this[0]).val();
            var search_string_2 = $(this[1]).val();
            // Do Search
            if (search_string_1 == '' || search_string_2 == '') {
                $("div#results").fadeOut();
                $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
            }else{
                $("div#results").fadeIn();
                $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
                $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
            };
        });

});
```

Comment: Can you provide me with full code

Comment: Could you show us the function where you perfom the search? (AJAX I guess)

Comment: Please post your AJAX call code

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward ajax is ok, everything works fine. I'm just trying to count number of divs within #result container as they are updated by ajax.

Comment: @user3275701 I understand it; but if the elements are not counted right it's because they don't exist at counting time, so probably your event fires before the ajax call is ended; for this reason more code will be helpful

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward oh you got the point, sorry. I updated post with ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of place the code in the `keyup` function set the counter in the `success` function right after the field is filled with data and you can count it.

Code:

```
// Live Search
// On Search Submit and Get Results
function search() {
    var city = $('input#search').val();
    var description = $('input#description').val();

    //$('b#search-string').html(query_value);
    if (city !== '' || description !== '') {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_php/search.php",
            data: {
                city: city,
                desc: description
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("div#results").html(html);
                $('#search_results').remove();
                $('#browse_wrapper').prepend("<p style='border-bottom: 1px solid #C5C5C5; margin-bottom: 20px;' id='search_results'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> <strong>" + $('div#results>div').length + "</strong> results for " + $('#search, #description').val() + "</p>");
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Genius and simple, and I'm busting my head, thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Your page search results dynamically so you need to use [event delegation method](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$(document).on("keyup",'#search, #description', function(){
```

Comment: I don't think it's a delegation issue, I think it's an AJAX result related issue

Comment: by search result the page's content is changed so I thought that.

Comment: Its not an ajax issue, it works fine.  Im just trying to count number of divs returned by ajax. To elaborate once more, everything works fine with ajax and live search, Im only trying to count number of returned divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with some delay like `setTimeout()` with `clearTimeout()`:

```
var t = "";
$('#search, #description').on("keyup", function(){

    clearTimeout(t);

    t = setTimeout(function(){
        if($('#search_results').length>0){
            $('#search_results').remove();
        }
    $('#browse_wrapper').prepend("<p style='border-bottom: 1px solid #C5C5C5; margin-bottom: 20px;' id='search_results'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> <strong>"+$('div#results>div').length+"</strong> results for "+$('#search, #description').val()+"</p>");
    },500);

});
```